# return latest document based on a element in marklogic

Tags: xquery, marklogic

There is a collection with 4 documents. I want to retrieve the document with latest timestamp.

The below query helps to sort in descending order but I want the **latest modified document**

```
 for $doc in fn:collection("/test")
 order by $doc//timestamp descending
 return $doc//id/text(),",",$doc//timestamp/text())
```

Output

```
1234, 2018-03-05T11:29:42.722Z
 5678,2018-03-05T11:29:42.715Z
 8976,2018-02-05T11:28:42.710Z
 8976,2018-02-04T11:28:42.716Z
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your for loop is already generating a sequence, so all you need to do is take the first item. And so you don't end up querying values for documents you don't want, move the output rendering portion of the query into a separate expression.

```
let $latest :=
  (for $doc in fn:collection("/test")
  order by $doc//timestamp descending
  return $doc)[1]
return $latest//id/text(),",",$latest//timestamp/text())
```

Now, if there is a range index on `timestamp` of type `xs:dateTime`, you can select the most recent document without first loading all those document into memory and sorting. However, you may have to replace `$doc//timestamp` with `$doc/path/to/timestamp` (no double-slash) for the query optimizer to automatically use a range index.

Comment: this works but for eg if I try to use 
```let $a := cts:collection-match("/test/*")``` and there are 2 collections ```/test/123``` and ```test/567```
I want to return the lastest of both the collections.The above solution doesnot work

Comment: Posted a new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49678817/search-latest-document-from-multiple-collection