# search latest document from multiple collection

Tags: xquery, marklogic

There are 2 collections /test/123 and test/567 I want to return the latest 
  document of  both the collections.

```
let $a := cts:collection-match("/test/*")
 for $t in $ a
 let $latest :=(
 for $doc in fn:collection( $t)
  order by $doc//timestamp descending 
  return $doc)[1]
 return fn:concat($latest//id/text(),",",$latest//timestamp/text())
```

- Is there a better to get the latest document from the collections
- I want the final output of query after searching both the collection to be in 
  descending order for timestamp

  Output

  ```
   1234, 2018-04-05T11:28:47.040Z

   4567,2018-04-05T11:28:47.722Z
  ```

Expected

`4567,2018-04-05T11:28:47.722Z
 1234, 2018-04-05T11:28:47.040Z`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the answer from @wst in your earlier question talking about just one collection (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/49678200/918496), can be adapted to work for multiple collections as well. It is mostly a matter of placing the parentheses differently. Moreover, fn:collection accepts a sequence too, so adapting the earlier solution would be almost trivial:

```
let $latest :=(
  for $doc in fn:collection(
    cts:collection-match("/test/*")
  )
  order by $doc//timestamp descending 
  return $doc
)[1]
return fn:concat($latest//id/text(),",",$latest//timestamp/text())
```

`<update>`

Re-reading the question (the added Expected section helped, thanks), I see I may have misunderstood the desired output. You are not looking for the most recent result across all matching collections, but you want the most recent of each collection, shown in descending order. That looks slightly different, and you weren't very far off at all. You just need a second order by clause:

```
let $a := cts:collection-match("/test/*")
for $t in $a
let $latest := (
  for $doc in fn:collection($t)
  order by $doc//timestamp descending 
  return $doc
)[1]
order by $latest//timestamp descending
return fn:concat($latest//id/text(),",",$latest//timestamp/text())
```

Having said that, there might be more performant ways of doing this with MarkLogic. If you have a dateTime range index on your timestamp, you could allow MarkLogic to make use of that to find the first in ascending or descending order real quickly. The clearest way of doing that is using [cts:search](http://docs.marklogic.com/cts:search) with a [cts:index-order](http://docs.marklogic.com/cts:index-order) argument. Something like:

```
let $a := cts:collection-match("/test/*")
for $t in $a
let $latest := cts:search(
  collection(),
  cts:collection-query($t),
  cts:index-order(
    cts:element-reference(
      fn:QName("","timestamp"),
      "type=dateTime"
    ),
    "descending"
  )
)[1]
order by $latest//timestamp descending
return fn:concat($latest//id/text(),",",$latest//timestamp/text())
```

`</update>`

HTH!

Comment: first solution caters gives   4567,2018-04-05T11:28:47.722Z , i want the final output to be

 ```4567,2018-04-05T11:28:47.722Z
 1234, 2018-04-05T11:28:47.040Z```

Comment: I gave a +1 for Geert's 'second' solution as your starting point. Anything you do with a FLWOR statement (ordering/filtering) will not scale nearly as well. The range index option is a perfect use of ML and the cts library.  Furthermore, even if I wanted lists of uri, timestamp, collection for some purpose, I would then have cts:co-occurrence available for other uses.

Comment: re " Anything you do with FLWOR statement (ordering/filtering) will not scale nearly as well. ", I disagree with- "Anything" as a general statement.  The ML XQuery compiler and runtime does optimize for use of indexes in many cases, and will fall back to non index use if it cannot.  The biggest problem is it is not at obvious when this happens or what choices were made.   For non experts, I suggest starting with basic FLWOR expressions and simple Xquery  where reasonable until the functionality  is correct then using the XQuery profiler to help optimize 'hotspot' functions'.